# MidiClientCreate notifyproc not getting called

Tags: ios, core-audio, coremidi

I have the following code where I want the function MyMIDINotifyProc to be called to notify me of changes to the midi devices connected to the iOS devices. 
However, strangely it is never called when i connect or disconnect devices - what could be the problem here?

Thank you. Help much appreciated.

```
void MyMIDINotifyProc (const MIDINotification  *message, void *refCon) {
    printf("MIDI Notify, messageId=%d,", (int)message->messageID);

}

/* csound MIDI input open callback, sets the device for input */ 
static int MidiInDeviceOpen(CSOUND *csound, void **userData, const char *dev)
{

    int k = 0;
    //6counter++;
    endpoints = 0;

    CFStringRef name = NULL, cname = NULL, pname = NULL;
    CFStringEncoding defaultEncoding = CFStringGetSystemEncoding();
    MIDIClientRef mclient = NULL;
    MIDIPortRef mport = NULL;
    MIDIEndpointRef endpoint;
    MIDIdata *mdata = (MIDIdata *) malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(MIDIdata));
    OSStatus ret;
    cdata *refcon = (cdata *) malloc(sizeof(cdata));
    memset(mdata, 0, sizeof(MIDIdata)*DSIZE);
    refcon->mdata = mdata;
    refcon->p = 0;
    refcon->q = 0;
    refcon->pnot = refcon->pchn = 0;

    cname = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "my client", defaultEncoding);
    ret = MIDIClientCreate(cname, MyMIDINotifyProc, refcon, &mclient);

    if(!ret){
        /* MIDI output port */
        pname = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "outport", defaultEncoding);
        ret = MIDIInputPortCreate(mclient, pname, ReadProc, refcon, &mport);
        if(!ret){
            /* sources, we connect to all available input sources */
            endpoints = MIDIGetNumberOfSources();
            csoundMessage(csound, "midi srcs %d\n", endpoints);
            midiDevicesArray = malloc(endpoints*sizeof(CFStringRef));

            for(k=0; k < endpoints; k++){
                endpoint = MIDIGetSource(k);
                void *srcRefCon = endpoint;
                MIDIPortConnectSource(mport, endpoint, srcRefCon);
                // insert into dictionary instead ?
                midiDevicesArray[k] = ConnectedEndpointName(endpoint);

            }
        }
    }
    refcon->mclient = mclient;
    *userData = (void*) refcon;
    if(name) CFRelease(name);
    if(pname) CFRelease(pname);
    if(cname) CFRelease(cname); 
    /* report success */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem on Mac OS X. The cause was that i didn't have a run loop in place. The documentation for CoreMIDI isn't quite extensive, but the MIDIClientCreate docs indicate that notifications are dispatched using run loop sources:

> Note that notifyProc will always be called on the run loop which was current when MIDIClientCreate was first called. [Apple MIDI Services Reference : MIDIClientCreate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMidi/Reference/MIDIServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010316-CHMIDIServiceshFunctions-SW54)

So a solution was to call `CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, true)` in my custom run loop. Since i created the `MIDIClientRef` on a secondary thread, i had to add this call to the run loop of my main thread as well (eventually this needs to be done for all parent threads). `CFRunLoopRunInMode` will process the input sources of the run loop and exits immediately in my case (third parameter is `true`), but you can also choose to block the thread until the run loop is stopped (`CFRunLoopRun`), maybe on a new thread, whatever fits your design best.

If you are not familiar with Apple's Core Foundation and Cocoa Run Loops yet, the following guide should be a good introduction: [Apple Threading Programming Guide : Run Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)